# How should I debug a failed Manipulate of RegionPlot?

Tags: manipulate, version-10, regions

I am trying to build a package that will display a sector of an ellipse where the angle is taken from a focus of the ellipse rather than from the center. The code seems to work fine when called with individual values.

A problem arises when I try to embed a call to the code within a Manipulate. Here is a simplified failing version:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    RegionPlot[
      Sector[5, 3, ang, ang + \[Pi]/6],
      PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}
    ]
  ],
  {{ang, 0, "Initial angle"}, 0, \[Pi]/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

When I move the slider, I can see errors at some different values of ang
(such as 1.5708 and 0.119381), while others work fine. The error message
says "The cell Line[{1,1}] is degenerate." and seems to be coming from 
BoundedMeshRegion.

I have tried several approaches to debugging the problem:

1) I tried removing the Manipulate and plugging in a failing value, but the code worked fine.

2) I tried Trace, but the output was quite long and unenlightening to me.

3) Incidentally, removing the PlotRange call removes the error message,
but the displayed plot is clipped on both ends.

My question is how to debug this problem? That is, how should I think
about attacking the problem. Alternatively, am I misusing the computational resources (e.g. RegionPlot) in some way?

Note, the code for the package is available here ([.txt](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Spencer.Rugaber/mathematica/Sector.txt) or [.wl](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Spencer.Rugaber/mathematica/Sector.wl)).
A secondary utility package is available [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Spencer.Rugaber/mathematica/UtilityFunctions.wl)
I am running Mathematica version 10.0.2.0.

Thanks.

Spencer

Comment: The code for the package does not contain code for helped functions on which `Sector` depends, so unfortunately I am unable to reproduce your code. Would you be able to you provide those as well?

Comment: I have added an additional link to the missing material in the question.

Comment: My original question was about debugging. Both answers got rid of the bug, but they did it without treating the problem as a "bug". That is, they determined that I was using the language inappropriately rather than incorrectly. Can anyone recommend a strategy for determining, when an error message shows up, whether to treat it as a traditional bug to be corrected or an indication of incorrect usage, to be rethought? If the latter, how should one attack a situation where the system is indicating incorrect usage, but it is not clear which program element is being used incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem reported in the question was a bad formula.
This led to a call to ArcCos that, with some arguments, produced a complex number as a result. When this value was given to any of the Region functions, an error resulted.

The only way that I could find to debug the problem was traditional: isolate a failing case, working step by step examining each computation.

Thank you for your answers, from which I learned a lot.

Spencer

Answer (score 3):

Manipulate typically changes the default value of the `$PerformanceGoal` control to "Speed" instead of "Quality", in order to speed up evaluation of dynamic content (see the first "basic example" in [its documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)). Typically this doesn't matter much, but in some cases this can influence the outcome of some algorithms that are sensitive to the working precision.

Unfortunately, something in your implementation is among these algorithms, even without `Manipulate`. Compare the following two results, obtained using arbitrary vs. machine-precision arguments:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Table[
  RegionPlot[Sector[5, 3, ang, ang + \[Pi]/6], 
   PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}],
  {ang, {Pi/20, Pi/20.}}
  ],
 ImageSize -> Full
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Fortunately, however, you can manually set the `$PerformanceGoal` setting within `Manipulate` by wrapping its argument in a `Block`:

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"},
  RegionPlot[
    Sector[5, 3, ang, ang + Pi/6], 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}
  ]
 ],
 {{ang, 0, "Initial angle"}, 0, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note also that I removed the `Show` wrapper because it wasn't really doing anything in your example, but that had nothing to do with your errors. This does not give me any more errors as I change the values of the `ang` parameter.

---

Note that the quality of the plot is still not very good. To improve on that, you can e.g. specify an arbitrary-precision step for the `ang` variable within Manipulate:

```
.
.
.
{{ang, 0, "Initial angle"}, 0, Pi/2, Pi/20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
(* Notice the Pi/20 increment *)
.
.
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I am going to try and **address some of your questions** in comments as best I can. Other shorter answers will just be added as comments below. Keep in mind that some of the issues you raise may be results of very complex interactions between features of the language, and some times "informed trial-and-error" is your best bet in figuring some of these issues out.

---

On the issue of machine vs. arbitrary precision numbers, **approximate numbers** are practically distinguished by an **explicit decimal point**. If you don't specify precision further, then they will be evaluated using machine precision. I would suggest the following documentation pages and how-to's that frame the issue well:

- the [Types of Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html) tutorial
- the [Machine-Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html) tutorial
- the [Arbitrary-Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) tutorial
- How to [Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)

---

On the Pi/2 in the `Manipulate`: the key is in the fact that `Manipulate`'s internals use *machine-precision increments* (as you can see in the value of the slider variable in the posted picture) even when you specify an arbitrary precision endpoint. The Pi/20 used above that induced `Manipulate` to use arbitrary-precision step increments instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have several followup question, which I have broken into separate comments. First, thank you for reminding of the difference between arbitrary and machine-precision computations. In your first example, it looks like the key to determining which is being used it whether Pi/20 is followed by a decimal point or not. Is this the case? In general, what are the rules for how the evaluator makes this distinction?

Comment: Later, in the second example, in the Manipulate[] variable specification (ang), you used Pi/2 (instead of Pi/2.), but the truncated sector appeared (as opposed to the sharp sector in the arbitrary precision version of your first example). Why doesn't the Pi/2 version work like the previous Pi/20 example? In your third example, why did the introduction of Pi/20 put the evaluation into arbitrary precision mode when the Pi/2 did not?

Comment: When I copied your first example into my notebook I was able to duplicate your graphs EXCEPT that both of the displayed regions in mine had been partitioned via a triangular mesh. These persisted even when I included the Mesh -> None option. Can you explain to me why I am seeing different output than you do and how I can control it?

Comment: I was not aware of $PerformanceGoal before you mentioned it (thank you). I have since done a search for a list of other global constants without success. Is there any way you would recommend of my learning about other resources like PerformanceGoal?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your second example (the Block[] with $PerformanceGoal) in my notebook and noted the same lack of "quality" improvement that you did. It looks like $PerformanceGoal is not helping here. Can you characterize when it should be applied?

Comment: @SpencerRugaber I tried to address the precision issue in an addition to my answer. I'll try to address the rest here.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber I am not sure why you get a **mesh**, nor how you could get rid of it. I can only think that it may have to do with a difference in MMA version or OS: I am using v. 10.1.0 on Win7-64 bit. What are you using?

Comment: @SpencerRugaber There is no repository for special global settings that I am aware of, but you can go explore a bit. Try evaluating `?? System\`$*`. This will give you a list of all variable names in the `System\`` context (i.e. mostly built-ins) that start with a `$`. Click on the names to get a short usage message. If something catches your eye, follow up in the full documentation.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber Can you clarify / rewrite your last comment? The formatting came out all jumbled and I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am running Mathematica 10.0.20.0 on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your second example (the Block[] with PerformanceGoal) in my notebook and noted the same lack of "quality" improvement that you did. It looks like PerformanceGoal is not helping here. Can you characterize when it should be applied?

Comment: @SpencerRugaber In that case `$PerformanceGoal` was not the culprit of the lack of quality; some internal numerical routine within `RegionPlot` is probably to blame. This is unfortunately a complex and rather opaque example compounding problems arising from `Manipulate` with others that came from within `RegionPlot`. It would be quite hard, if at all possible, to pinpoint the exact origin of the problem "from the outside", i.e. without having intimate knowledge of e.g. what `RegionPlot` is doing exactly under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `Sector` returns a region for which `RegionMember` can calculate its formula.  `RegionPlot` is quite a bit faster on this fairly simple formula than on the region.  Further, you don't run into the symbolic-numeric problem of reducing the `RegionIntersection` in whatever way *Mathematica* does under the hood.  (I suspect it is using a algebraic/symbolic solver like `Reduce` on approximate machine-real input, whereas `RegionPlot` on a formula is purely numeric.  I confess I don't fully understand the problem, because I am unable to reproduce it outside of `Manipulate`.)

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  RegionMember[Sector[5, 3, ang, ang + π/6], {x, y}] // Evaluate,
   {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}],
 {{ang, 0, "Initial angle"}, 0, π/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

You can control the quality of the plot with options like [`PerformanceGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)`-> "Quality"`, [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html)`->`[`ControlActive[15, 51]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html), and [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html).  Note the `Evaluate` is very important, or `RegionPlot` will take a very long time.  This ensures that `RegionPlot` is passed the algebraic formula; without it, the formula will be recalculated every time `RegionPlot` tests whether a point is in the region or not.

**Side remark**

It seems to me that you would do better with `ParametricPlot` than `RegionPlot`.  It is usually much more efficient, both in speed and quality.  All you need is to be able to parametrize the region.  I think this draws the picture you want:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  (1 - s) {FocalDistance[5, Eccentricity[5, 3]], 0} + s Polar2CartesianE[5, 3, t],
  {s, 0, 1}, {t, ang, ang + π/6},
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, Axes -> False],
 {{ang, 0, "Initial angle"}, 0, π/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It will always have a nice, sharp corner at the focus.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have several followup questions, which I have broken out into separate comments. The first set has to do with regions. I infer from your response that there are two separate kinds of regions: those defined by formula (e.g. ImplicitRegion and RegionPlot) and those defined by geometrical construction (e.g. HalfPlane). Have I got this right? You mention the use of RegionMember, which was not included in my original code. Is this used to convert between the two forms? Overall, is this the "symbolic-numeric problem" to which you refer?

Comment: You mention the use of MaxRecursion. My code is not explicitly recursive. Is there some implicit recursion going on?

Comment: You mention the use of ParametricPlot, and I like your solution. How would I know in general when it is better to use ParametricPlot than RegionPlot? Is it simply a matter of performance or are there semantic reasons?

Comment: For PlotPoints, how did you choose the values 15 and 51? Are odd multiples of 3 preferred, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: With regard to the ParametricPlot, I am unfamiliar with the idiom (1-s)*f + s*g(t). Can you shed some light on this for me?

Comment: @SpencerRugabe `MaxRecursion` controls how many times plot functions subdivide the domain to get a smooth graph (quality vs. time). IMO, it is always better to use `ParametricPlot`, **if** you can parametrize the region.  15 & 51: Odd numbers are sometimes better than even (for symmetry); often it makes no difference (as here). Multiples of 3: coincidence. The formula $(1-s)*P + s*Q$ parametrizes a line segment from $P$ to $Q$ for $0 \le s \le 1$, a useful formula to know for graphics. If $P$ or $Q$ depend on another parameter $t$, then you get a region swept out by a varying line segment.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber The "symbolic-numeric problem" was intentionally obscure because it is based in part on experience and intuition, not on direct knowledge.  Functions like `Simplify` and `Reduce` often have difficulty with expressions that have approximate numeric coefficients because they have a hard time telling when things are equal (due to round-off error). as well as perhaps other obstructions.  I suspect region functions often invoke some of these solvers....

Comment: @SpencerRugaber ...  `RegionPlot` on an algebraic inequality works by plugging in a bunch of points and seeing when the left-hand side is greater than the right-hand side and vice versa.  Then it guesses that the boundary of the region must be in between.  To see what `RegionMember` does just execute `RegionMember[Sector[5, 3, ang, ang + π/6], {x, y}]` by itself and see what you get. (It will be an inequality.)  So this form of `RegionPlot` works purely by numerical evaluation and not by trying to simplify complicated algebra.